# Updating database table values through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

My test.php page is as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Setting</h3>
<p>Name:<input type="text" id="updatetherone1"/></p>
<p>Email:<input type="text" id="updateotherone2"/></p>
<p>
<input id="updateone" type="button" value="Save"/>
<span id="updateotherotherone"></span>
</p>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

My ini.php page is as under:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['state'] ='2';
$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','people');

?>
```

My test1.php page is as under:

```
<?php
include 'ini.php';

if (isset($_POST['name'], $POST['email'])){
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($POST['name']));
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($POST['email']));

$update = mysqli_query("UPDATE state SET Name='$name', email='$email' WHERE Id=".$_SESSION['state']);

if($update === true){
echo 'Setting have been updated.';
}else if ($update === false){
echo 'There was an error updating your setting.';
}
}
?>
```

My ajax.js page is as under:

```
$('[id=updateone]').click(function(){
var name=$('[id=updateotherone1]').val();
var email=$('[id=updateotherone2]').val();
$('[id=updateotherotherone]').text('Loading...');

$.post('test1.php',{name:name,email:email},function(data){
$('[id=updateotherotherone]').text(data);
});
});
```

Ultimately code is not working nor do it is displaying any error, I suspect there is something wrong with test1.php page, can anybody guide please:

Comment: Ugh, your code isn't very structured... Why haven't you put your form elements in a "form" element in your HTML? If JavaScript is disabled your form will never work. You've over complicated a very simple AJAX form. Also, I would read up on jQuery form submitting, there are many tutorials on the Internet...

Comment: Use a "form" and you could quite easily write a jQuery function to post the form to the action URL and receive/process the response.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comment from Big Chris

you also should try to set the variable Id='$_SESSION[\'state\']' in quotes and because you use quotes inside this variable you have to use backslash so php can set the quotes correctly without interrupting the variable